# Find Probability density function on an arbitrary day

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

> The waiting time of a bus as T(measured in mins). Assume on weekdays (Mon to Fri), T is an exponential random variable with mean 3 mins. On weekends (Sat to Sun), T is an exponential random variable with mean 5 mins.
>
> Find the probability density function of T on a arbitrary day.

I know how to find pmf, but if I need to find pdf, what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to combine the two pdfs that you are given.  For a random day, there is a $\frac 27$ chance it is a weekend.  Use that to weight the two pdfs.

Comment: so it is 3*5/7+5*2/7?

Comment: The pdf is a function of time.  Your expression gives the expected waiting time.  The one for weekdays is a decreasing exponential.  The one for weekends is another decreasing exponential.  They are scaled so the area below them is $1$.  Scale them as I suggested and add them together.

Answer (score 0):

For any arbitrary day the random variable T will have a mixture distribution with pdf

$f(t) = \frac{5}{7}f_1(t) + \frac{2}{7}f_2(t)$

Where $f_1(t)$ and $f_2(t)$ are the pdfs of exponential distribution with mean 3 and 5 respectively